# How do I generate an accessToken for Facebook's Graph API after I successfully authenticate using Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've successfully authenticated through Firebase's Facebook implementation but after analyzing the user object that's being sent back I'm not seeing the accessToken that I need to query Facebook's Graph API.

I see fields like displayName, photoURL, email, providerId, refreshToken, and a ton of other fields but I do not see the accessToken I need to query Facebook's Graph API.

Comment: Are you saying that the object you get back from some API call doesn't have the property you're looking for?  Could you edit the question to show the exact code that isn't working the way you expect?  The documentation seems clear about how it works: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sign in with popup or redirect, you can get the Facebook access token after sign-in:

```
// For popups.
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result.credential.accessToken);
});

// For redirects.
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult.then(function(result) {
  if (results && result.credential) {
    console.log(result.credential.accessToken);
  }
});
```

Note that Firebase Auth discards the Facebook OAuth refresh token after sign in. If you need the Facebook access token on a regular basis, you will need to sign in with Facebook SDK (or REST API) and use the Facebook access token to sign in directly with Firebase Auth via `signInWithCredential`.